# Make select2 boxes wide enough for contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

[I have this table in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLzxo9ba/3/). I want the `name` column to be wide enough to fit the names available in the `options` without truncation.

I have explored the suggestions in the [Select2 appearance documentation](https://select2.org/appearance#container-width), but those don't seem to provide what I'm seeking.

If possible, I would like it to automatically shrink or widen to fit the longest available text in the `data`.

[image]

```
<table>
<tr><td>name</td><td>sex</td><td>age</td></tr>
<tr><td><select class="name" multiple="multiple"><option></option></select><td><input name="sex"/></td><td><input name=
"age"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><select class="name"/><td><input name="sex"/></td><td><input name=
"age"/></td></tr>
</table>

<script>
var options = [
  {id: 1, text: 'Alexander Allen Abrahms III'},
  {id: 2, text: 'Benjamin Barry Bautista Jr.'}
]



$(".name").select2({data:options, placeholder: 'Full name'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css and define style on select tag like this:

```
<select class="name" style="width:100%" multiple="multiple">
   <option></option>
</select>
```

and define table cell width:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th width=50%> Name </th>
       <th width=25%> Sex </th>
       <th width=20%> Age </th> 
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody> Your table body</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is yours edited code in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3hrdrjj4/1/

EDIT:

Fiddle with select width responsive to picked options and fixed placeholder https://jsfiddle.net/3hrdrjj4/5/

Comment: If possible, I would like it to automatically shrink or widen to fit the longest available text in the `data`.

Comment: Probably it was from catch. I can see it working now.

Comment: @Hatshepsut then you shoul rather use $('.name').select2( dropdownAutoWidth : true,
    width: 'auto'); and not a css 100 width%.

Comment: That works very well for the content. Is it possible to also get the placeholder to work? https://jsfiddle.net/3hrdrjj4/3/

Comment: @Hatshepsut I think this is your solution https://jsfiddle.net/3hrdrjj4/5/

Answer (score 1):

if i didn't get it wrong u want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpRs8.png) right?

you can just simply add `style="width: 250px;"` to the inputs you desire.
or add `width: 250px;` to the `name` class.

https://jsfiddle.net/wLzxo9ba/5/

Comment: If possible, I would like it to automatically shrink or widen to fit the longest available text in the `data`.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to resolve it is:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%">name</td>
        <td style="width:15%">sex</td>
        <td style="width:15%">age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%"><select class="name" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%"><option></option></select>
        <td style="width:15%"><input name="sex"/></td>
        <td style="width:15%"><input name="age"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%"><select class="name"  style="width:100%"/>
        <td style="width:15%"><input name="sex"/></td>
        <td style="width:15%"><input name="age"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```